# Sum boundaries of the number of permutations with cycles of 4 different lengths.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

The question is how many permutations $\sigma\in S_n$ are there such that $\sigma^6=identity$.

So I'm pretty confident that my answer $\sum_{k=0}^{⌊\frac{n}{6}⌋} \sum_{p=idk}^{idk} \sum_{l=idk}^{idk} \frac{n!}{k!p!l!(n-6k-3p-2l)!(6)^k(3)^p(2)^l} $ is correct except the sum boundaries, where $k,p,l$ and $(n-6k-3p-2l)$ are the number of cycles with length $6,3,2$ and $1$ respectively.

Could someone explain to me how the sum boundaries work in this case?

Comment: Do the same as you did for $k$. EG $p$ goes from 0 to $\lfloor \frac{ n-6k } { 3 } \rfloor$.

Comment: So l goes from 0 to⌊$\frac{n-6k-3p}{2}$⌋?

Comment: Yup. $\quad$ Though it's not clear to me if they want a closed form answer, instead of using this summation approach.